# Chi-Square degrees of freedom confusion

Tags: probability, distributions, inference

Wikipedia states that a $\chi^2$ distribution has $k$ degrees of freedom and is the sum of $k$ independent standard normal random variables (makes sense). But Newbold's book 'Statistics for Business and Economics' states that

$\chi^2 \left( n - 1 \right) = \frac{ \left( n - 1 \right) \cdot s^2 } { \sigma^2 }$
and I quote '$\chi^2$ distribution with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom'.
So is it $k$ dof or $n - 1$ dof?
Am I possibly missing some notation common sense or?
Thank you.

Comment: One is chi square distributed with k degrees of freedom and the other with n -1. There is no contradiction between the two statements.  Please use $$ to write math formulas.

Comment: oh...so they are the same. Thanks and sorry for that ugly formula. Will use $$ next time.

Comment: $S^2$ is not the sum of independent Normal variables.  It's a multiple of the sum of *interdependent* variables, because each one of them includes the same arithmetic mean in its construction.

Comment: Welcome to CV! BTW: this is not a stupid question. Just sayin'…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many test statistics follow the $\chi^2$ distribution. There are quite a lot of $\chi^2$ tests, and all have different formula to calculate the value of $df$ (degrees of freedom). A few examples:

- Pearson's $\chi^2$ test (of goodness of fit): $df = k - 1$ (or $df = k - p - 1$), where $k$ is the number of classes (and $p$ is the number of estimated parameters of the investigated distribution, if any)
- $\chi^2$ test that the variance of a normally distributed population has a given value based on a sample variance: $df = n - 1$ (where $n$ is the sample size)
- $\chi^2$ test of independence: $df = \left( r - 1 \right) \cdot \left( c - 1 \right)$ (where $r$ is the number of rows, $c$ is the number of columns in the contingency table)

For more examples, please check the [$\chi^2$-test wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Pearson's_chi-squared_test).

So there isn't any contradiction here, everywhere there are $df$ independent normally distributed random variables in the background somehow, and $df$ sometimes equals $n - 1$, sometimes $k - 1$ (here $k$ is the $k$ from the Pearson's $\chi^2$ test above, not the $k$ in your question), sometimes some other formula, depends on the test.